# Python wheel job - module not found

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

**Issue:** I made a wheel out of a very basic module, installed it on a Databricks cluster. When creating a job of type 'Python wheel', the job fails to run because it cannot find the package.

---

The setup is very simple. I have a source code folder:

```
src
|-app_1
  |- __init__.py
  |- main.py
```

Where `main.py` contains:

```
def func(): 
    print('Hello world!')
```

Then, I do the following:

1. Build `src` as wheels `demo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`.
2. Install `demo-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl` in the Databricks cluster. I then validate that the wheel was built and installed correctly. I know this because I am able to run `from app_1.main import func`, then calling `func` succeeds. This is the only wheel installed in the cluster.
3. Create a job of type Python wheel, then set package name as `app_1` and entrypoint as `main.func`. When I run the job, I get an error that `app_1` cannot be found.

[image: Job Config]

[image: Error Banner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get this to work is to update `__init__.py` with something like:

```
from my_package import main
```

Then in your databricks job, your entry point would be: `main.main` (assuming you have a function `main` in `main.py`

Answer (score 2):

You have to name your wheel - in setup - as the same name you will call in databricks task scheduler:

```py
setup(
    name="app_1.main",
    ...
)
```

In Databricks task scheduler:
`Package name: app_1.main` and `Entry Point: func`

Under the hood Databricks reads the metadata from package and consider the entire wheel as a package, doing `import app_1.main`.

If your package don't have the same name in setup metadata the scheduler doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep **init**.py empty. In setup.cfg,  declare an entrypoint function

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
    sample_entrypoint_name = app_1.main:func
```

In Databricks job UI simply mention the entrypoint name (sample_entrypooint_name). If you have argeparse declared inside your 'funct' function, mention them as  arguments inside parameters section.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set package to `app1.main` and entry point to `func` because documentation says that it will call `$packageName.$entryPoint()`, and in your case the full command is `app1.main.func()`

Comment: Same result unfortunately: `Run result unavailable: job failed with error message Python wheel with name app_1.main could not be found`. Driver logs: `PackageNotFoundError: app_1.main`

Comment: Ah, you need to add a dependent library, by specifying the path to it on DBFS… you simply don’t have your code attached to a job

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far. The specifying DBFS path is only present for a job type 'Python'. But for job type 'Python wheel', it asks for .whl uploaded as a library, I've also tried uploading it (in addition to having it already installed in the same cluster), but alas same error.